# UINavigationBar titleTextAttributes - not applied during transitions

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have give my nav bar titles a larger font like this:

```
let navBarTitleTextAttributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24.0, weight: .black)
]
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = navBarTitleTextAttributes
```

However, when navigating backward in the view controller stack, the title on the previous view controller always defaults to normal size until the animation is complete, then it pops back up to the larger font. Here's what I mean:

[image]

This makes having the larger font completely unacceptable and I wonder why we're even given that option if the nav bar title always defaults to system font/size during transitions. Is there a workaround for this? i.e. to have the title of the previous view controller also appear with the larger font during the transition?

Comment: This code is in a general style manager, not a view controller. This is Xcode 11. What should the replacement code be that applies to the nav bar appearance in all cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, good news and bad news. Good news is I found that this was being caused by another line of code:

```
UILabel.appearance().font = defaultFont
```

Apparently this somehow affects the navigation bar title font, ONLY when transitioning backward in a nav stack.

Bad news is that there's no `appearanceWhenNotContainedIn` class methods on UIAppearance. So you can either set the general appearance of UILabel or UINavigationBar, but not both.

Comment: Quite interesting result actually. You might file a bug report with Apple as this is rather unfair of them.

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce based on the info you've provided. Using all and only the information you've given, here's what I see:

[image]

So my guess is that you yourself are doing something you haven't told us about that sets the navigation bar's title text attributes back to the default before the pop animation gets started.

Comment: Also that dark slide behind the nav bar is suspicious and makes me think something else is wrong here.

Comment: Indeed, it was a UILabel.appearance() call. See separate answer.